# Check values between GROUP BY and a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Fob', 'Lob', 'Joe', 'Roe', 'Qoe'],
                'Country': [US,UK,UK,DE,US,AU],
                'Languages Known': ["Python, Java, C++","Java","Python","Python, C++","C++","Python"]})

df



Name    Country     Value   
 Bob     US          Python, Java, C++      
 Fob     UK          Java
 Lob     UK          Python
 Joe     DE          Python, C++
 Roe     US          C++
 Qoe     AU          Python
```

My Goal is to deduce the percentage of developers who know python in each country.

```
Country     Percentage   
US          50      
UK          50
DE          100
AU          100
```

Until now I have grouped the countries with index
countries = df.groupby('Country').count().reset_index()
how do I compare a group's values to other columns
also need to count the no of "Python"s in a country and percentage

Thank you.

Comment: Use `df["Languages Known"].str.match("Python")` to get the rows that know Python.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183699/annotate-each-row-with-percent-of-total-for-group-by-in-pandas for how to get a percentage in a group

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
df_out = ((df['Languages Known'].str.split(',').explode() == "Python")
                               .sum(level=0)
                               .groupby(df['Country'])
                               .mean())
df_out
```

Output:

```
Country
AU    1.0
DE    1.0
UK    0.5
US    0.5
Name: Languages Known, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved!

Answer (score 2):

Another option for *this use case*

```
df['Languages Known'].str.contains('Python').groupby(df['Country']).mean()
```

Output:

```
Country
AU    1.0
DE    1.0
UK    0.5
US    0.5
Name: Languages Known, dtype: float64
```